# How to perform a rotation using a movement of GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a unity project for rotating a sphere using hand motion (XR Interaction Toolkit).

Basically when I pinch with my left hand and move my left hand to the left the ball rotates to the left and so on in every direction, using transform.position. The problem is that every time I return to the starting position by releasing the pinch and then doing it again, the ball returns to its starting rotation.

There is a way to consider only the movement of the hand and not the position in space.

This is the code i'm using:

```
void Update()
{
    // Verify Pinch 
    leftPinch = isPinchLeft();
    rightPinch = isPinchRight();
    
    //Perform Rotation
    if (leftPinch == true && rightPinch == false)
    {
        // Assuming this script is attached to the GameObject whose rotation you want to convert
        Quaternion rotationQuaternion = transform.rotation;

        // Calculate the direction vector from gameObject1 to gameObject2
        direction = position2 - position1;

        // Calculate the target rotation based on the direction vector
        Quaternion toRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction, Vector3.down);

        // Smoothly interpolate between the current rotation and the target rotation
        gameObject2.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(gameObject2.transform.rotation, toRotation, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

}
```

There is a way to consider only the movement of the hand and not the position in space.

Thank you.